# Are there any pre-conditions or required settings to print/merge documents in 4.7?

Tags: error, core

Since CiviCRM 4.7 it is possible to print/merge documents not only as a pdf-file but also as an odt, docx or html file.

Does the function to create odt or docx files require any particular setting, installed libraries etc? I did not find any documentation and wanted to ask before I start debugging.

I have a "fresh" CiviCRM 4.7.16 instance and I am able to create pdf and html files but not docx or odt (File not found error).

Comment: I guess I would check for 'phpoffice/phpword' library, although composer should know to install that as per https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/dbccfacb43e4046e596bdeea2b3414bc0bac6222/composer.json#L23 & from https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17607 & https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17608.

Comment: Turn on debug & backtrace and post the error here.

Comment: Eli: Thanks, I will have a look at those links. Coleman: Once I start debugging I will deinitely do that but I actually wanted to know if it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue on an installation with PHPOffice.

PHPOffice is automatically installed via composer in CiviCRM, but apparently composer fails to check for needed PHP extensions. In my case php-zip was missing, and after installing that everything went fine.

I am not sure if composer should check the requirements, or if they aren't properly configured. Eli's comment helped a lot debugging this for me!